# Per-Pixel Lighting in WPF

Tags: wpf, shader, phong

Is it possible to implement per-pixel-lighting in WPF 3d application (C#) by using their shader effects?

I have a basic 3d application running in WPF but it only shows Gouraud Shading, by interpolating shaded colour values between vertices to the inner of the polygons. I tried to implement a per-pixel lighting approach, like Phong, but I realize that I do not seem to have access to interpolated normals in the WPF pixel shader effects.
Is this the limitation of WPF, where one should better go with C++ and OpenGL/DirectX directly?

Comment: you can still go with xna to avoid native programming. I always use this demo as an example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RDIeijJkV14. its made in xna&silverlight

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know, yes it is a WPF limitation...contrary to the OpenGL where you can do per-pixel shading, the WPF only allows you to work on a meshGeometry.

I think a way to go with it, would be to create textures that contains your shader effect, and then apply it per triangle.
This would take a longer amount of computation time, but should work.

Regards

Comment: Pixelshaders are also available in DirectX. It is a WPF limitation. Putting the shading in the texture is a hack, it does not take light and movement into consideration and will look very wrong when moving objects, lights or the viewpoint.